# new_excerpt_more link not working properly

Tags: functions, excerpt, wp-list-pages, read-more

My "Read More" button is linking to the current page page instead of the excerpt page it is suppose to be linking to.  Here is my function in function.php file:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
return ' <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> ...Read More</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

This is occurring in in excerpts being displayed from a custom walker for wp_list_pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global `$post` variable is filled on by running post through the loop (`the_post()` method or function, `setup_postdata()` function). If you look at the source for `Walker_Page` it is not running a loop and so does not make posts' data available through `$post`.

Since `excerpt_more` is not provided with info on the post either, you would need to track post data on your own and access it inside your filter function.